# Connecting To Local mySql Database

Tags: mysql, windows

Currently I am connecting to an online mySql database. I would like to switch it to a mySql database on my local hard drive and am having problems with the syntax.  Unlike the online one I have no UserID or Password. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
(mysql_real_connect (conn,"urlock.db.5513143.hostedresource.com","urlock","passxxx","useridxxx",0,NULL,0) !=0);
```

tried this:
    (mysql_real_connect(conn,"c:\urlock.db","urlock","","",0,NULL,0) !=0);

didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second parameter needs to be a host which represents a network connection.  It cannot be an absolute file reference like you might do with MS Access files.  So, you need to install MySQL5.X on your system as a service.  If you've done this, verify it by either looking for an open port of 3306 (default) via a 'netstat -an' command or simply look in your services for 'MySQL ....'.

If not, download it here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Once you get this you will be able to import the this database locally and be able to access it very similar to the online version.  i.e. (mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","urlock","someuser","somepass",0,NULL,0) !=0);

Importing/exporting can be tricky but to point you in the right direction look into the mysqldump command.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe the second parameter should be the host. If it is a local mySQL, the
   host is localhost.
2. The default username is usually 'root'.

Try this:

```
(mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","urlock","","root",0,NULL,0) !=0);
```

Comment: Thank you, Tania. Still a little confused. New to this. My file is located here  C:\FILEBLOCK\urlockCS.adp it was an Access 2010 file converted to MySQL if that makes any difference. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) installations of MySQL should have default accounts. There should at least be a root account. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a CONNECTIONSTRING

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

con.Open();

If you add your database in visual studio under Dataconnections, you can see the connection string under properties

ADDED:

If its an sqllite db, you need to use an SQLCeConneciton

private static string connectionString = @"Data Source=path/to/the/database/db.sdf";
 private static SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

Comment: Thank you. I am using mySql 5.0